# scala, I lose the type information when using pprint

Tags: scala

I would expect that `toPrettyString1` and `toPrettyString2` get the same result, but it seems that `toPrettyString1` losses the type information, and `pprint.tokenize` cannot the fields and print it nicely.

Why is so, and how to solve it?

```
libraryDependencies += "com.lihaoyi" %% "pprint" % "0.4.1"

case class Entry(id: Int, text: String)
val entry = Entry(1, "hello")

def toPrettyString1[T](o: T) = pprint.tokenize(o).mkString

def toPrettyString2(o: Entry) = pprint.tokenize(o).mkString

println(toPrettyString1(entry))  // I get Entry(1,hello), not what I want
println(toPrettyString2(entry))  // I get Entry(1, "hello"), as expected
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pprint library uses a `PPrint` type class to determine how a value of a particular type should be printed. If you have a completely unconstrained type `T`, you'll get a `PPrint` instance that simply calls `toString` on the value, which means you won't get quotation marks or the nice escaping pprint provides.

This is really all pprint can reasonably do if it knows nothing about the type, and even that is arguably too much—many type class-based libraries simply do not provide default instances like this even when there is a possible default interpretation of what the type class operations should do.

`toPrettyString2` works as expected because you're calling `tokenize` with a value that's statically typed as `Entry`, which `PPrint` can provide a better instance for. If you want this behavior with a generic type, you'll have to add a context bound:

```
def toPrettyString3[T: pprint.PPrint](o: T) = pprint.tokenize(o).mkString
```

And then:

```
scala> println(toPrettyString3(entry))
Entry(1, "hello")
```

Now you're calling tokenize not with some completely generic `T`, but specifically with a `T` that you have a `PPrint` instance for, and when you call `toPrettyString3` with an `Entry` argument, the library will provide a `PPrint` instance with the quotation marks, escaping, etc.

---

The `T: pprint.PPrint` syntax is just sugar for an implicit argument:

```
def toPrettyString3[T](o: T)(implicit pp: pprint.PPrint[T]) =
  pprint.tokenize(o)(pp).mkString
```

You didn't define an implicit `PPrint[Entry]` instance, but the library is able to [derive reasonable instances](https://github.com/lihaoyi/upickle-pprint/blob/master/pprint/shared/src/main/scala/pprint/PPrint.scala#L426) for case classes using a macro. You could also define your own instance if for some reason you wanted different behavior, though, and it would override the derived instance.

Comment: I tried and it works as you say. However I still do not understand it. Where is the implicit or magic that transforms my `Entry` instance to a `pprint.Print` instance? can IntelliJ help me find this implicit?

Comment: @DavidPortabella Just updated the answer. In short, there's a macro in pprint that derives instances for case classes.

Comment: thx! this is a follow-up question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40049207/scala-different-behaviour-when-calling-mapf-vs-mapv-fv